# How does Phrases in Gensim work?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, gensim

I am using Gensim Phrases to detct n-grams in my text. Thus, I am interested in knowing the mechanism that Phrases uses to detect these n-grams in the text. Can someone please explain the mechanism used in Phrases in simple terms?

Answer (score 2):

As the gensim tool cites the very famous paper by Mikolov - "[Distributed Representations of Words and Phrases...](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf)" using which it is implemented. In the paper if you look at the section "4 Learning Phrases" they give a nice explanation of how n-grams are calculated (Equation 6).

[image]

So, if want to count bigrams this formula is straight-forward; score(wi, wj) is the score between any two words occuring together. But when counting trigrams, 'wi' will be a bigram and 'wj' will be a word. And same follows for any number of grams.

Answer (score 1):

Gensim detects a bigram if a scoring function for two words exceeds a threshold (which is a parameter for Phrases).

The default scoring function is what is in the answer by flyingDope, but multiplied by vocabulary size (use `help(Phraser)` or see the [gensim's Github repository](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim) (gensim/models/phrases.py)):

```
def original_scorer(worda_count, wordb_count, bigram_count, len_vocab, min_count, corpus_word_count):
   #...
   """
    worda_count : int
        Number of occurrences for first word.
    wordb_count : int
        Number of occurrences for second word.
    bigram_count : int
        Number of co-occurrences for phrase "worda_wordb".
    len_vocab : int
        Size of vocabulary.
    min_count: int
        Minimum collocation count threshold.
    corpus_word_count : int
        Not used in this particular scoring technique.
    """
    #...

    return (bigram_count - min_count) / worda_count / wordb_count * len_vocab
```

Another implemented score function is `npmi_scorer` based on a paper by G. Bouma.

I think n-grams for n>2 are done by applying bigram detection `n-1` times.

If `min_count` (i.e. $delta$) was zero and if instead `len_vocab` we multiplied by `corpus_word_count`, then the result of `original_scorer` would be essentially the ratio of the probability to see `wordb` following `worda` and the unconditional probability to see `wordb` at a random position, that is how many times the presence of `worda` increases the probability to see `wordb` in the next position.

I cannot understand why gensim chose to use `len_vocab` here, but perhaps they had some reason to. You can pass your own scoring function as well.